# Left side of fieldset hidden due to overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

I have a field set where I used `overflow: hidden` in order for it not to collide with a nother div floating left to it.

The problem is that the over flow hidden block the left side of it. 
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/opmaster/uXdX4/3/) is a jsfidde. sorry for the long code, no time to screen...

Comment: I didn't understand.. What is your question? What are you trying to achive?

Comment: Could you please clean your code and only add the code which has to do with your question. It's a bit hard to understand and edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the look you are trying to achieve but you can find my attempt [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L7VGF/).

I removed the right margin from div.rightside and the float and overflow properties fron div.leftside.

```
.rightSide {
    float: right;
    /*margin: 0 100px 0 0;*/
    max-width: 40%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 40%;
}
.leftSide {
    /*float: right;
    overflow: hidden;*/
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    width: 500px;
}
```

The visual results may be undesirable depending on the size of screen this page will be rendered to so I would suggest you use [the 1140px CSS Grid System](http://cssgrid.net/)

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you tried to do:

**rightSide** should be with `float:right`;

and **leftSide** should be with `float:left`;

just look on your **width**... it's should be set to **both div**

take a look on the example:
move the middle line to the left and you see the div go left..

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uXdX4/4/) <--- Click on the link

[image]